# Facebook SDK 3.0 - Tutorial

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

Hey can someone point me in the right direction of a good Facebook tutorial for android?  The tutorial their developer site isnt all that good.

This is what i've came up with so far:

```
public static final int FBResultCode = 100;
private static Session.StatusCallback sharedFBStatusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
        if(exception != null)
            Log.e("fb error", exception.toString());
        switch(state)
        {
        case OPENED:
                            //login successful
            break;
        case CLOSED:
        case CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED:
            closeFBSession();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

public static void openFBSessionWithLoginUI(boolean loginUI)
{
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && 
            !session.isOpened() && 
            !session.isClosed()) 
    {
        ArrayList<String> perms = new ArrayList<String>();
        perms.add("user_likes");
        perms.add("user_birthday");
        perms.add("read_friendlists");

        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(rootActivity)
        .setCallback(sharedFBStatusCallback)
        .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
        .setLoginBehavior(loginUI? SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO: SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_ONLY)
        .setRequestCode(FBResultCode)
        .setPermissions(perms);

        session.openForRead(openRequest);
    }
    else 
    {
        Session.openActiveSession(rootActivity, loginUI, sharedFBStatusCallback);
    }

}

private static void closeFBSession()
{
    Session currentSess = Session.getActiveSession();

    if(currentSess != null)
    {
        currentSess.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}
```

However this returns an error:

> E/fb error(3601): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session:
>   an attempt was made to open a session that has a pending request.

What am i doing wrong? Or better yet, what is the best way to handle fb logins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i have used this tutorial and worked properly:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Theres also this one, wich is pretty detailed.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

I also use this logic to log in with an existing token since in my app it always connects with the samer user as some sort of a host of events.

[Android Facebook SDK - Get user events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606514/android-facebook-sdk-get-user-events)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Gilson, this tutorial also very helpful for those who try to connect facebook into their android application.

http://ericosgood.com/prog/facebook-android-sdk-tutorial/

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/

http://tutotialandroid.blogspot.com/2013/06/easy-facebook-android-sdk-simple.html

Androidhive is also such a useful link..

Comment: first both are old tutorials and last one not opening. Do you have link for any other tutorials?

Comment: i don't know it helps or not but u can also check this
http://androidadnan.blogspot.com/2013/06/easy-facebook-android-sdk-simple.html

Comment: after this you can also check this https://developer.stackmob.com/android-sdk/developer-guide#Facebook